# how send friend request to a person in Facebook through iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to send friend request through iPhone application? if yes, please help me.  I've searched in web but I didn't get solution.

I got the following code to send app request not to send friend request

```
 NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];
[variables setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Come and join XYZ App."] forKey:@"message"];
[variables setObject:@"url" forKey:@"picture"];       
[variables setObject:@"Hello" forKey:@"name"];
[variables setObject:@"Description" forKey:@"description"];

[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/feed",facebook_user_id] 
                      andParams:variables 
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to send friend requests, this must be done using one of Facebook's interfaces

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Graph API doesn't support adding friends. You can get list of friends from the Facebook profile but you can not send the friend request from Facebook Graph API.