# How to send add friend request (to facebook user) from iOS application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I know there are lot of questions on this topic but none of those have satisfactory answers. Again I am not so confident about help as 2 of my last 3 questions are unanswered. Well Still, ma question is, **Is there any way we can send friend request to any facebook user from one iOS application?** Of course we have user id of that user.

As I have googled much and went through many links including

1. [how send friend request to a person in Facebook through iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835311/how-send-friend-request-to-a-person-in-facebook-through-iphone-app)
2. [Can a facebook friend request be sent from my own app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360882/can-a-facebook-friend-request-be-sent-from-my-own-app)
3. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
   etc..

And finally I found it:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/friends?id=100002487216939&app_id=123050457758183&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response/

This dialog do the same what I want. So is there any equivalent for this in graph. Or something in iOS sdk, `FBDialogueDelegate`. Any thing that can help me out.

Comment: 2 of your last 3 questions went unanswered because they were poor, stop complaining and read the FAQ

Answer (score 1):

For [user-to-user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) requests, you can do this (using ARC):

```
 NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: message, @"message", title, @"title", nil];
[[self facebook] dialog: @"apprequests"
                          andParams: [params mutableCopy]
                        andDelegate: delegate];
```

For [app-to-user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) requests, you can do this:

```
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: message, @"message", nil];
[[self facebook] requestWithGraphPath: @"[FRIEND ID]/apprequests"
                            andParams: [params mutableCopy]
                        andHttpMethod: @"POST"
                          andDelegate: delegate];
```

Make sure you have the right access tokens and the correct Facebook configuration (canvas page setup etc.) for each.

Comment: You have are suggesting way to request friend to JOIN THE APP, what i need  is to send a friend request FROM the application.

Comment: It is not possible and it is against [Facebook policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) IV.2 & IV.3 at least