# Send Facebook friend request via iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, fbconnect

I'm trying to add a friend request feature to one of my apps. I've done quite a bit of research, and I've found out that I can't do that via the graph api. I've also looked into dialogs, and that isn't supported in FBConnect.

So my only option now would be to pop up a UIWebView and do it and format the url like this: `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/friends/?id=FRIEND_ID&app_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI`. That's not a problem, but if the user isn't logged in with Facebook on mobile safari, they will have to log in and that can get quite annoying.

Have any others dealt with this problem? Any good work-arounds?

Comment: There was actually a duplicate question today. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11521580/1487063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friend requests always need to be authenticated from the request sender side, hence the user will have to log in when using the friend request dialog if they are not already logged in.

Comment: That's not my problem. To go through the authentification, I use a dialog method with FBConnect for iOS. The only way I am aware of sending friend requests is via a UIWebView. I was wondering if there was a way to do it natively with an FBRequestDelegate.