# How to make a friend request with facebook ios sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook

i'm using the facebook iOS sdk.
I need to send friend requests between users of facebook, from an iOS app.
I know that can not be sent via graph API. I'm trying to through dialog of facebook i do not know how.
Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
Facebook *face = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"APP_ID" andDelegate:self];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"user_id",  @"id",
                               nil];

[face dialog:@"me/friends"
        andParams:params
      andDelegate:self];
```

With this code i get a dialog with this text: "The page you requested was not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution.
I have created a NSMutableDictionary to make a "appRequest" with their corresponding parameters but finally indicated that the type of dialogue is a "friends".
It's a strange solution but it works.

```
Facebook *face = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:FBSession.activeSession.appID andDelegate:nil];
face.accessToken = FBSession.activeSession.accessToken;
face.expirationDate = FBSession.activeSession.expirationDate;
if ([face isSessionValid]){
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"My Title", @"title",
                                   @"Come check out my app.",  @"message",
                                   userId, @"id",
                                   nil];
    [face dialog:@"friends"
       andParams:[params mutableCopy]
     andDelegate:nil];
}
```

Comment: Joan Facebook is Facebook sdk class

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
 NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: message, @"message", title, @"title", nil];
 [[self facebook] dialog: @"apprequests"
                      andParams: [params mutableCopy]
                    andDelegate: delegate];
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521580/how-to-send-add-friend-request-to-facebook-user-from-ios-application) for further details and also this [document.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/)

Comment: I want to make a friend request, this is an app request.

Comment: I think u can't do it in facebook sdk, read I.2 in [facebook sdk policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy). may be facebook framework in ios6 may help u